# ios, require purchase of physical product to start using application

Tags: ios, mobile

I have a client who wants a mobile app that requires the user to enter a code to start using the application.

This is basically a promotional campaign for a new product: each product bought gives the user a code that he can put in the app to "advance" to the next level. The "game" consists of six levels. All users that finish the game will participate in a draw to win some prizes.

Is this allowed? I am concerned that the user cannot use the app without buying the product first.

All I could find, here and on Google, refers to selling stuff in app but nothing about this particular case.

Final thought: if this is not the right place to ask this question then I apologize...

Comment: This probably isn't the right place for this type of question.  Saying that, I'm fairly certain (not positive) that it's okay.  Most of the restrictions appear to be around in app purchases or linking outside the app to make a purchase. https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval /guidelines.html

Answer (score 3):

> 11.1
>
> Apps that unlock or enable additional features or functionality with
> mechanisms other than the App Store will be rejected
>
> 11.16
>
> Apps may enable additional approved features or functionality when
> used in combination with specific approved physical products (such as
> a toy) as long as the additional features and functionality are either
> completely dependent on such hardware (for example an App that is used
> to control a telescope) or also available through the App without the
> physical products, such as by way of reward for achievement or by use
> of IAP.

They just don't want you using any trick to avoid giving Apple their share. If your app is strictly promotional, you may get a pass for 11.1.

11.16 is for things like Skylanders. You can also follow the above clause `or also available through the App without the physical products, such as by way of reward for achievement`.

They do allow apps for sweepstakes/raffles, as long as you don't buy the raffle in the app, so it might fall into that category:

> Contests, sweepstakes, lotteries, and raffles
>
> 20.1
>
> Sweepstakes and contests must be sponsored by the developer/company of the App
>
> 20.2
>
> Official rules for sweepstakes and contests, must be presented in the App and make it clear that Apple is not a sponsor or involved in
> the activity in any manner
>
> 20.3
>
> It must be permissible by law for the developer to run a lottery App, and a lottery App must have all of the following characteristics:
> consideration, chance, and a prize
>
> 20.4
>
> Apps that allow a user to directly purchase a lottery or raffle ticket in the App will be rejected

If you're worried about 11.1, I think one trick here is to make it not usable at all until you enter a code. "Additional" being the key word in "additional features". Then, it's the NetFlix model.

You'll need to provide codes for Apple to test the app.

Comment: 11.1 means that what you're doing is likely to get rejected.